# Spark-Java: How to replace a column name in Dataset<Row> to new name?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading data from `MongoDB` using `Spark` as JSON:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
....
..    
Dataset<Row> ds = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();
```

I need to store this DF to Hive.
The problem is that one of the column name in the MongoDB is `Timestamp` which is a reserved word in Hive.
So, the JSON-data from MongoDB contains one key as `timestamp`.
I need to replace this json key `"timestamp"` to `"timestamp_"`.
How do I replace the column name `"timestamp"` in `Dataset<Row> ds` to `"timestamp_"`?

Comment: `ds = ds.withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "timestamp_")` ?

Comment: Thank you @Grisha. If suppose this `timestamp` column is an element inside a `struct`, then can I do `ds = ds.withColumnRenamed("struct1.timestamp","struct1.timestamp_")` ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple way to rename nested columns. I posted one possible solution below. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rename a nested column, you can do the following:

1. flatten/explode all the struct columns
2. rename the column
3. collapse all the columns back

Let's say your dataset schema looks like that:

```
root  
      |-- col1
      |-- col2
      |-- struct1
      |    |-- timestamp
      |    |-- a  
      |    |-- b
```

So you can do the following

```
ds = ds
        .select(col("*"), col("struct1.*"))
        .withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "timestamp_")
        .select(
                 col("col1"),
                 col("col2"),
                 struct("timestamp_", "a", "b").as("struct1")
        );
```

In case you want to rename a nested column inside an array, you first should expand the array by using `explode` function.

```
ds = ds.select(col("a"), col("b"), explode(col("struct1")))
```

Then you can rename the nested column as described above. If after the renaming you want to collapse the structs back under array, use `groupBy(...).agg(collect_list(...))`.

Comment: Thanks @Grisha, that was really helpful!! The struct you have provided is very close to what I have, except that the `struct1` is an `array(struct("timestamp", "a", "b"))`. I tried to use the code you provided. But I am getting error that only `struct type can be expanded`. I tried to use `ds.select(col("*"), col("struct1.*")).withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "timestamp_").select(col("col1"),col("col2"),array(struct("timestamp_", "a", "b")).as("struct1"));` And it throws error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types`

Comment: @aiman, in order to expand an array you should use `explode` function rather than "star". See my edited answer.